# Why doesn't obj['NonExistentKey'] throw an error in TS?

Tags: typescript

Take the following code snippet, I'd expect an error on the 2nd line but there isn't one.

```
const foo = { someKey: 'foo' };
foo['NonExistentKey'].bar.baz // no errors
foo.NonExistentKey.bar.baz    // NonExistentKey doesn't exist
```

[ts playground link](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=const%20foo%20%3D%20%7B%20someKey%3A%20'asdf'%20%7D%3B%0Afoo%5B'NonExistentKey'%5D.bar.baz%20%2F%2F%20no%20errors%0Afoo.NonExistentKey.bar.baz%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20NonExistentKey%20doesn't%20exist)

Is there any way to catch this??

Answer (score 3):

In order to make transition easier from JS to TS it was considered that dynamic access to objects, ie access using `[]` should not error and just return any.

This is ofcourse a very big hole in the type system and there is a compiler flag to close it, the flag is called `noImplicitAny`. This will make your code raise error an error as expected (but it will also make any places the compiler assumes `any` an error as well).

In the playground you can go to options and enable this option and you will see an error as expected.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to catch this type of error is to enable TypeScript's `strict` mode, or to turn on the `noImplicitAny` flag in your `tsconfig.json` file.

Once one of those in enabled you'll get an error like this:

```
wat.ts:2:1 - error TS7017: Element implicitly has an 'any' type because type '{ someKey: string; }' has no index signature.
foo['NonExistentKey'].bar.baz
```

Without those flags, `foo` is implicitly typed like `const foo: { [index: string]: any, someKey: string }`. I believe the justification for this is that people coming from JavaScript often arbitrarily index into arbitrary objects and expect that to work, so in non-strict mode it is allowed even if is not particularly type safe.

Generally, I find the non-strict behavior confusing and error prone, so I recommend you always have `strict: true` in your `tsconfig.json` file.

Full documentation on the various compiler options available are here: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html

Docs on `tsconfig.json` in general are here: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig-json.html

More information on index signatures in general is here: https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/docs/types/index-signatures.html